# How did he make his code work without defining txtTitle and txtMessage?

Tags: c#

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vAx0kObdps
[image]
https://pastebin.com/MHyQD4cd

namespace Note_taking_App
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
DataTable table;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Messages", typeof(String));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

        dataGridView1.Columns["Messages"].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns["Title"].Width = 140;

    }

    private void bttNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTitle.Clear();
        txtMessage.Clear();
    }
```

In this video he is making a form, which I have tried to replicate. However, I realized that he never defined two variables, and still is able to get the form to work. How is this possible?

Full code linked in the pastebin link.

Comment: @TheGeneral  i'm fairly new to coding as a whole so i'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @TheGeneral this is winforms not WPF

Comment: @Jonesopolis ahh ok.

Answer (score 2):

When you add UI elements to a form in the designer, they get added to the partial class for the form.  In the solution explorer, if you find your form, you should be able to expand it and see the designer file that has the partial class where the controls are defined in the code.

You can see his slightly covered solution explorer where he has the form expanded [here](https://youtu.be/8vAx0kObdps?t=383)

Comment: do you mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEsc8.png

Comment: @Max0815 yes - the `Form1.Designer.cs` class

Comment: So since my code doesn't work, what should I change to make it work? In the video he doesnt touch the solutions explorer, so how did he do it?

Comment: you'll have to add it to the designer like he did.